# Visual Studio - Add resharper shortcut to command

Tags: visual-studio-2013, command, resharper

I am currently using resharper and alt+shift+L command is used a lot by me. I would like to know if it's possible to add a command on some toolbar so that I can just click that directly instead of switching my hand between mouse and keyboard and then pressing alt+shift+L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just add the `ReSharper.ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer` command to a toolbar.

The easy way to find the command name is to go to Tools → Options → Keyboard, and try to assign any other command to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Visual Studio will tell where the shortcut is already being used.